# Hibernate - Just want to query table but it tries to create the table as well

Tags: sql, hibernate

I try to create a simple Hibernate example which reads some articles from a database. The following code shows me the article description from the (already existing) table Art(icle). But it also tries to create the Table "Art" if openSession is called. I just want to read from the existing table, so why it tries to create the article table before it shows the existing entries?

```
sessionObj = buildSessionFactory().openSession();
Query<Art> query = sessionObj.createQuery("from Art",Art.class);

for(Article a : query.getResultList()) {
    System.out.println(a.getDesc());
}
```

Comment: Check the Property "hbm2ddl.auto" in hibernagte config file<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>. If its Create, then is deletes the schema and creates the schema .

Answer (score 1):

Which values you use in your configurations ?

From docs you can use:

> hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto
>
> Automatically validates or exports schema DDL to the database when the
>   SessionFactory is created. With create-drop, the database schema will
>   be dropped when the SessionFactory is closed explicitly.
>
> validate | update | create | create-drop

from this

> 1)validate: validate the schema, makes no changes to the database.
>
> 2)update: update the schema.
>
> 3)create: creates the schema, destroying previous data.
>
> 4)create-drop: drop the schema at the end of the session.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I use <property name = "hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

Comment: In this case it should only create the tables if the table doesn't exist.

Comment: So I switched to "validate" and Hibernate says "Schema-validation: missing table". So you should be right but It reads from the table without problems if I use update. Hibernate shows:
create table Art (Artnr int not null, Artgroup CHAR(5), Description VARCHAR(30), Price money, primary key (Artnr))

And the table structure in the database is:

Artnr (PS, int, NOT NULL)
Description (varchar(30), NOT NULL)
Price (money, NULL)
Artgroup (char(5), NULL)

Comment: When use UPDATE , it creates the table with empty rows. So you have no DATA inside. And the queries are executed ok. If you use UPDATE, then do not drop the tables. And do some inserts. It should work.

Comment: The user has no rights to create. So the existing table is used. I think maybe it is a problem with the money type mapping... But I have no idea (MSSQL)

Comment: It is not the user you use, it is hibernate who creates, update,validate schema. If your user has no create rights, than how it recreate the table when open session is called ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177946/discussion-between-knowledge-and-simion).